# PHP: two images (after resize with ratio) into shape as one image

Tags: php, image

I want to resize my two images to fit best and keep ratio and put them into shape (two circles). I am wondering about easier method to resolve my problem. I want to get this result shown on image below:

[image]

1. Load src image 1 and src image 2: I got this
2. to square with aspect ratio:  I use [Eventviva/Php-image-resize](https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize)
3. to circle: I found some code for this on stackoverflow, but still finding and trying to get the best
4. to shape: I don't know how to do it (my idea written below)

My idea: I was thinking about use imagecopymerge in this way: open imagecircle1, then add white outline border on imagecircle2, then set imagecircle2 with border to right bottom corner and save but first of all - it wont be transpared because of white border, moreover I am sure that easier way exists but I cant find it.

Any ideas how to get result shown on image with easier way? Or if my idea is correct, can you help me a bit with shape?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Lukasz, a good place to start is to use [image transformations service](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations/) via URL where you can mesh your images together in various ways, applying filters, backgrounds, reshape, etc.

HTH.

Comment: I will check this. I have question, I can use demo cloudinary to transform images on-the-fly, then save on my server? And one more, I always put images to transform in .webp format, and after transform I want it with .png extension, is it possible? I checked documentary and I found fetch_format (in URL use f_) and 2 params - auto: .webp or .jpegx format (depend on user's browser) and png: convert to .png. I tried to use f_png in URL and it didnt work, any ideas?

Comment: Certainly, you can always save the transformed images anywhere you'd like. Indeed, Cloudinary will automatically [convert the image format](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#image_format_conversion) by changing the extension to the filename, or you can do that with the [fetch_format](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#fetch_format). Please submit a support ticket if this does not work for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point, Jay! In this case I made sure to only include perma-links but your suggestion is certainly more robust. Thank you.